# How to sort array based on subarray value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16059
            [product_id] => 4013
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4013
                    [name] => XYZ
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16060
            [product_id] => 4462
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4462
                    [name] => MNOP
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16061
            [product_id] => 4473
            [Product] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4473
                    [name] => ABCD
                )

        )
)
```

How to short this array using Product > name in ascending order. I can do using for-each loop, but there is any method to  without loop ?

Comment: "without loop" not really, because also the native functions (usort) loop under the hood. [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) would be one way to go btw.

Comment: @Jonnix that have different array

Comment: @YogeshSaroya So? The principle is still the same.

Comment: _“that have different array”_ - so what? Then adapt it accordingly, after you made the effort to understand how this works in principle …

Comment: array_multisort(array_column(array_column($arr, 'Product'),'name'), SORT_ASC, $arr);

Comment: @RakeshJakhar  (Y)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    return $a['Product']['name'] > $b['Product']['name'];
});
```

[usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: With case of strings it's better to use `strcmp` because with `>` your strings will be converted to ints, I presume.

Comment: Yes, they will be converted. But if they are only strings then it should word as it will compare in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 3):

Use [usort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) with [strcmp()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php):

```
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
   return strcmp($a['Product']['name'] , $b['Product']['name']);
});

print_r($array);
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/Cb5S5

Answer (score 1):

Here is the snippet,

```
$t = [];
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $t[$key] = $value['Product']['name'];
}
array_multisort($t, SORT_ASC, $arr);
```

First, fetch the data of that name and create an array.
Pass the relevant array for sorting criteria to a multidimensional array.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/laWO1).